# Dividing in assembly trouble

Tags: assembly, x86

I'm working on a simple program that adds two numbers together and gives the average for them. My trouble is with the division. I set bl =2 and use it to divide into the ax register which has the correct integer however, I can not seem to get a correct answer. for example when I divide 8 by 2 I get a 1c in the al register.

```
mov dl, bl    
add dx, 30h; two user entered numbers add together and converted
mov ah, 2h
int 21h

;mov dx, 0h  
mov ax, dx ; 
mov bl, 2
div bl ; al, ah for results
```

Answer (score 7):

You added `30h` to `dx`, so you're dividing `38h`, not `8`. And `38h / 2 == 1Ch`.

As a side note, in the special case where you're dividing by a power of 2 (such as 2, 4, 8, 16, etc), you can do that by shifting log2(divisor) bits to the right instead. In this case that would be `shr ax, 1` (or `sar ax, 1` if you want to treat `ax` as a signed number).